# VimLeave getChar doesn't work with :wq

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, getchar

Vim version: vim 8.0

Let's say I define a function that requires user input and I want it to run when vim quits. So I write in my vimrc:

```
function! OnQuit()
    redraw
    echon "Run quit function? [y/N] "
    let c = nr2char(getchar())
    if c == "y"
        redraw
        echo "yes!"
    endif
endfunction

autocmd VimLeave * call OnQuit()
```

If I quit with `:q`, or `:wqa`, it works like a charm and accepts the first key entered. If I do `:wq` to quit, getchar() doesn't seem to kick in and I need to type the key and then press enter.

Does anyone know why this only works with `:wqa` and `:q` but not `:wq`? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

use `QuitPre` event will do what you want. But I cannot explain why `VimLeave` made `getchar()` need an `Enter`

Comment: QuitPre does something different from what I want - I want to run this when I exit vim, not when I quit (which can happen if I :q from one window).